# Как динамически создавать IList

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе на WPF есть 32 кнопки. При нажатии на некоторые из 32 кнопок, их индексы записываются во временный список **IList** (так кнопки выделяются), а при нажатии на кнопку "**Добавить в группу**" их индексы записываются в постоянный список **IList**.

Проблема в том, что можно создать неограниченное число групп и для каждой нужен свой **IList**, а я не знаю, как их динамически создавать. То есть если выделить другие кнопки и нажать "**Добавить в группу**", то нужно индексы этих кнопок записать уже в новый **IList**. А у меня он сейчас только один, не считая временный

```
IList<int> newGroup = new IList<int>(); // То самый единственный список
IList<int> selectedTeethGroupTemp = new List<int>(); // Временный список

// Кнопка "Добавить в группу"
private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        // ...

        // Копируем временный список в новый
        newGroup = selectedTeethGroupTemp.ToList();
    }
}

// Здесь я могу обращаться к элементу IList по имени 
// А если создать динамически новый список, то как к нему обращаться?
void CheckForSelectedListBoxItem()
{
    if (listBoxItem0.IsSelected)
            // ...
}
```

**Правка 1:**

Создал цикл для обработки списка, чтобы для всех кнопок группы менять цвет, но программа даже не заходит вовнутрь данного цикла:

```
List<List<int>> newGroup = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> selectedTeethGroupTemp = new List<int>();
IList<Button> toothButtonsList;

void StoreToothButtonsInList()
{
    toothButtonsList = new List<Button>
    {
        button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7,
        button8, button9, button10,button11,button12,button13,button14,button15,
        button16,button17,button18,button19,button20,button21,button22,button23,
        button24,button25,button26,button27,button28,button29,button30,button31,
    };
}

private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newGroup.Add(selectedTeethGroupTemp);
    selectedTeethGroupTemp = new List<int>();

    foreach(var i in selectedTeethGroupTemp)
    {
        // Сюда программа даже не заходит
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        toothButtonsList[i].BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

Comment: listBoxItem0 а это к чему относится? Можно ли больше кода для понимания задачи?

Comment: Вероятно, нужен список списков: `List<List<int>>`. Или словарь списков: `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.

Comment: @ На форме есть компонент `ListBox` и при нажатии на "**Добавить в группу**" в нем появляются элементы `listBox`. Если на них нажимать, можно выделять определенные группы. Постарался убрать лишний код, т.к. много всего накручено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<List<int>> newGroup = new List<List<int>>(); // То самый единственный список
List<int> selectedTeethGroupTemp = new List<int>(); // Временный список

// Кнопка "Добавить в группу"
private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newGroup.Add(selectedTeethGroupTemp);

    foreach(var i in selectedTeethGroupTemp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        toothButtonsList[i].BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    selectedTeethGroupTemp = new List<int>();
```

Comment: Добавил работу с циклом

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает